# How to set proxy settings in firefox addons?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to set a proxy setting, when the addons installed. I follow documentations here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/proxy/settings. But, its not worked.

Manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Secure Proxy",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Secure Proxy.",

  "permissions": [
    "proxy"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts" : ["js/background.js"]
  }
}
```

background.js

```
let proxySettings = {
  proxyType: "manual",
  http: "118.97.151.130:9090",
  httpProxyAll: true
};

browser.proxy.settings.set({value: proxySettings});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the scheme e.g.

```
http: "http://118.97.151.130:9090",
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from erosman is correct. I may add that in order to make this extension work, you will need to allow it to run in Private Windows : https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/extensions-private-browsing. If you don't, it will throw an exception and will not change your proxy setting.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a comment rather than an answer. Wait to have enough rep.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Just thought it was usefull to add because I searched for this for hours. Unfortunately I can't comment yet sorry.