# FireFox proxy connection using firefox proxy api

Tags: proxy, firefox-addon-webextensions, http-proxy

I am having a proxy server and want to inject in my firefox browser using firefox api below after injecting using

```js
let proxySettings = {
  proxyType: "autoDetect",
  http: "proxy.org:8080",
  socksVersion: 4,
  httpProxyAll:true,

};

browser.proxy.settings.set({ value: proxySettings });
```

after inject to verify whether my proxy is injected successfully or not i am executing below code:

```js
browser.proxy.settings.get({ incognito: false }, (config) => {
    if (config.levelOfControl === "controlled_by_this_extension") {
      console.log({config})
    }
})
console response:

{
  "proxyType": "autoDetect",
  "autoConfigUrl": "",
  "autoLogin": true,
  "proxyDNS": false,
  "httpProxyAll": true,
  "socksVersion": 4,
  "passthrough": "",
  "http": "proxy.org:8080",
  "ssl": "proxy.org:8080",
  "socks": ""
}
```

but when I browse the internet and check my ip at at https://whatismyipaddress.com/ it shows my local ip means my proxy server is not injected successfully, need a solution regarding this

Able to inject proxy server successfully.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set proxy settings in firefox addons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57470131/how-to-set-proxy-settings-in-firefox-addons)